# how to use custom pointers in osmdroid?

Tags: android, icons, maps, osmdroid

I am using OSMDroid and this code gives default markers to point my location. How do i put custom markers in place of the default markers? How do i import a new drawable?

```
anotherOverlayItemArray = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
anotherOverlayItemArray.add(new OverlayItem("KTM2", "KTM2", myLocation));
 ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> anotherItemizedIconOverlay = new
          ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>( this, anotherOverlayItemArray,myOnItemGestureListener);

      mapView.getOverlays().clear();   
      mapView.getOverlays().add(anotherItemizedIconOverlay);  
      mapView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a specific marker to each OverlayItem:

```
OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem("KTM2", "KTM2", myLocation);
Drawable myMarker = getResources().getDrawable(markerResId);
item.setMarker(myMarker);
anotherOverlayItemArray.add(item);
```

You can also get rid of the ItemizedIconOverlay/OverlayItem approach by using the [OSMBonusPack Marker](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0).